# javascript setInterval doubles the console.logs

Tags: javascript

I am using a self invoking function within a script I have called from a Chrome extension I am making.

I have a simple `setInval` every 30 secs. My problem if doubles the `console.log` every 30 sec instead of just one log.

So when the pages loads it prints once. Then 30 seconds latter instead of printing one more it prints 2 logs. Then 4, 8, 16 times etc.

Very strange.

```
(function check() { 
    console.log("Exists!"); 
    return setInterval(check, 30000); 
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` sets up an *interval* - it will call the callback every interval. If you call `setInterval` twice, 2 callbacks will run periodically. If you have a `setInterval` which recursively calls itself, you'll eventually get 4, then 8, then 16, etc intervals.

Either remove the recursive call:

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log("Exists!"); 
}, 30000);
```

Or use `setTimeout` instead:

```
(function check() { 
    console.log("Exists!"); 
    return setTimeout(check, 30000); 
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the interval inside the function so it logs once, but will also relog the values each time. Intervals persist, so the intervals add up.